# How can I permanently disable all achievements and related messages?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'd like to play StarCraft 2 without seeing all the achievements and related messages. Is there any way I can permanently get rid of them?

Comment: Play offline. Problem solved.

Comment: not real easy when I'm playing vs. humans on battle.net

Comment: Do you consider a match statistic screen a stupid mess too? It kind of gets in the way of playing, too...

Comment: Nah, that gives me interesting info about the match.  Like, I can see who went for eco or military when, and how it impacts the game result.  The difference is that the stats are relevant info, but the achievements are irrelevant to the play of the game.

Comment: Disable achievements? Whyyyyy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't disable them without going offline. I'm sorry to say it looks like you're just going to have to suffer through the achievement system like the rest of us. Maybe you should consider getting as many achievements as possible so you either run out of them, or become so used to seeing the notifications that you start to automatically ignore them.